# Java: PUT request without id getting submitted as POST

Tags: java, jersey, java-ws

I have create and update api calls for same entities. If user send a `PUT` request with no object id, controller accepts it as a `POST` request and creates a new object. 
 How can I prevent that?

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response create(Entity entity){}


@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response update(@PathParam("id") int id,Entity entity){}
```

Is there a way to make request parameter required for update? That may resolve the issue as well.

Comment: A shot in the dark, try adding `@Path("/")` to the POST method. In theory, this will make the POST method to only work if nothing else is added to the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a RegEx pattern from your `@Path`.

Syntax:

```
    @Path("/{" variable-name [ ":" regular-expression ] "}")
```

Example:

```
    @Path("/{id: <replace_with_reg_exp>}")
```